# Text misalignment in HTML table output by PHP and displayed in Browser

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
function my_fav_quote_show_optin_form() {   

if (!empty($_POST['my_fav_quote_email'])) {

    my_fav_quote_opt_in();
}
    $out2 = '';

    $out = '<form action="" method="post" id="requestQuote">';
    $out .= '<table style="padding="0px" width="40px">';
    $out .= '<tr><td>Name:*</td><td><input type="text" name="my_fav_quote_name" id="my_fav_quote_name"/></td></tr>';
    $out .= '<tr><td colspan=1></td></tr>';
    $out .= '<tr><td>Email:*</td><td><input type="text" name="my_fav_quote_email" id="my_fav_quote_email"/></td></tr>';
    $out .= '<tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>';
    $out .= '<tr><td>Message:</td><td><textarea cols=20 rows=5 wrap="hard" name="my_fav_quote_message" id="my_fav_quote_message"></textarea></td></tr>';
    $out .= '<tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>';

    $out .='<tr><td colspan="2">';
    if ( function_exists( 'my_fav_quote_display' ) ){
        $out .= my_fav_quote_display();
    }
```

the thing is that this is a plugin of wordpress which i am modifying for my need  their is misalignment of the word "message" i.e is it is appearing too low with respect to text areabox and also cols and row syntax are not working have tried applying style top ,bottom and also tried margin but the message word is not moving from the place  .please click on add to quote for seeing the widget where the problem is [a link](http://mattisonsdev.info/mattisons-catering-event-quote/)

Comment: Use a tool like Firebug or your browsers integrated developer tools to inspect that cell and see what CSS styles are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">Message</td>
```